# Apache 2.4 multiple instances on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.4

Apache ships with a script for creating multiple instances on the same server, which is exactly what I want to do. The first instance is happily up & running on ports 80 (http) and 443 (ssl).

File */usr/share/doc/apache2/README.multiple-instances* explains:

> An example script
> that demonstrates what else needs to be done can be found in
> /usr/share/doc/apache2/examples/setup-instance. Use with:

```
sh /usr/share/doc/apache2/examples/setup-instance xxx
```

> Adjust the configuration in /etc/apache2-xxx, especially the listen ports in
> ports.conf and in the virtual host directives in
> /etc/apache2-xxx/sites-enabled/*.

> You can then use a2enmod-xxx, apache2ctl-xxx, ... as usual, and they
> will affect the new instance of apache2.

So I run:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/doc/apache2/examples/setup-instance mautic
```

Then I changed the ports to 8089 and 448 in */etc/apache2-mautic/ports.conf* and in my virtual host directives in */etc/apache2-mautic/sites-enabled/* and tried to start the service:

```
sudo systemctl status apache2@mautic.service
```

However, this service won't start, because it appears to be using the old configuration files, hence I get the following output:

```
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

```
sudo apache2ctl-mautic -V
```

```
 Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_PROC_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/etc/apache2"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/lib/apache2/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/var/run/apache2.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="apache2.conf"
```

Comment: I made all the steps you did (adding `systemctl start apache2@mautic.service`) on a Debian 12 system (in LXC container) and everything works fine, I have apache2.service using port 80 and apache2@mautic.service using port 8089. Perhaps you could start again from scratch and see how it behaves? Btw, this script is Debian-specific, not upstream (it's provided in the package sources inside the debian/ directory). Copies in /usr/local/sbin might not work as intended, maybe they used to work but don't anymore with the switch to systemd (so apache2ctl-mautic -V does not reflect reality in my case).

Comment: Actually it shows build time information. Run time should be used: `apache2ctl-mautic -D DUMP_RUN_CFG` where here in my test I can see `ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2-mautic"` `PidFile: "/var/run/apache2-mautic/apache2.pid"` etc.

Comment: Thanks @A.B for taking the time to test! Confident it was my fault, I re-run the steps correctly, and now it works. Not sure what mistake I did however...